# Export/See Dynamics CRM dialog responses

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2015

I have a customer survey dialog associated to the case entity. Is it possible to see/export the responses recorded through dialogs in Dynamics CRM?

Comment: is your dialog a JavaScript Dialog or is it a Dialog Process created within Dynamics

Comment: It is a dialog process created within Dynamics

Answer (score 1):

Dialog responses are stored in CRM Database. You can access this data with the following query:

```
SELECT
fps.name
,fps.processsessionid
,fps.startedbyname
,fps.startedonutc
,fps.regardingobjectidname
,fwl.stepname
,fwl.description
,fwl.interactionactivityresult
FROM dbo.FilteredProcessSession fps
LEFT JOIN dbo.FilteredWorkflowLog fwl ON fps.processsessionid = fwl.asyncoperationid
```

Unfortunately, answers are stored as XML formatted text so it will require some extra effort to access required information.

Example:

```
<interactionResponse promptText="How do you do?" label="I am well. Thank you!" type="string" value=" I am well. Thank you!" />
```

Above mentioned information may be also accessed using Dynamics 365/CRM SDK.

My recommendation is to use custom entity (ex. “Interview Answer”) to log required information. If you do this, you will be able to query dialog results just from the CRM UI.